# Phrase is repeated within a cell - how do I remove ONLY the second instance and keep the first?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column that has a repeated phrase in it. Example:

Cell A2:

> Weather Report. **Clouds: Gray;** Rain: Light; **Clouds: Gray;** Temperature:
>   Hot

Cell A3:

> Weather Report. Tuesday. **Clouds: Gray;** Rain: Heavy; Pollution: Bad; **Clouds: Gray;** Bananas: Yellow

The Phrase "Clouds: Gray;" repeats. I want to make it so that the second instance of the phrase is removed from the cell, but the first one remains. The end result should look like this:

Cell A2:

> Weather Report. **Clouds: Gray;** Rain: Light; Temperature: Hot

Cell A3:

> Weather Report. Tuesday. **Clouds: Gray;** Rain: Heavy; Pollution: Bad; Bananas: Yellow

Since there's no consistency in the cell aside from this one repeated phrase, I have no clue where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the only issue "Clouds: Gray", or do you need to find any collection of words that is repeated?  If the latter, what are the parameters or patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SUBSTITUTE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php) function

> SUBSTITUTE( text, old_text, new_text, [nth_appearance] )

has a parameter called *nth_appearance* which reads

> Optional. It is the nth appearance of old_text that you wish to replace

---

So your formula is

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Clouds: Gray;",,2)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to illustrate how to pull the second set of text out.
The following in some other cell on the same row such as b2 will remove the second occurance by replacing the second instance with "" using a substitute formula

- =SUBSTITUTE(C2,"Clouds: Gray;","",2)

to get this in A2, you would need to use a paste special value.
however, I do not recommend it as a long term fix. For a short deadline, it might be an ok work around. Fixing the source of the problem or fixing the formula in A2 would be better, but would need to know what formula is in A2 or where was the data copied from.